# Rqc package error: "GhostScript was not found"

Tags: r, ghostscript

I'm following the [Rqc package documentation](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Rqc/inst/doc/Rqc.html) so i typed the following :

```
library(Rqc)
folder <- system.file(package = "ShortRead", "extdata/E-MTAB-1147")
rqc(path = folder, pattern = ".fastq.gz")
```

but i'm getting the following error :

> Error in bitmap(file = filename, width = width, height = height, res =
> 300) :    GhostScript was not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm running the latest version of RStudio (0.99.491). First, make sure you have downloaded GhostScript ([here](http://ghostscript.com/download/)). Then, go to the directory where you installed it, and find the path to the executable. Then, do this:

```
Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.18/bin/gswin64c.exe")
```

The path refers to my specific .exe, so yours may be different. Basically, the function that is throwing the error is looking for `R_GSCMD` to give it a path to run GhostScript. It didn't find one, so it threw an error. By setting `R_GSCMD` to the path, it now knows where to look.